# Which parameters I need to put in the headers and body type while testing in Postman?

Tags: paypal, authorization, postman, token

```
curl -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
-H 'Authorization: Basic {Your Base64-encoded ClientID:Secret}' \
-d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code={authorization_code}'
```

I am trying this but isnt giving me the token output.
[image]

I have put although the `Authorization: Basic {Your Base64-encoded ClientID:Secret}`
into **Headers**.
Am I doing something wrong?

This is the output I am getting in Postman.

```
{
    "name": "AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE",
    "message": "Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header.",
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#error",
            "rel": "information_link"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Add authorization , basic and give clientid as username and password as secret

remove the custom header basic, postman will add the basic authentication header automatically

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the action of the request supposed  to be post and in the postman it looks like you put get action.

Comment: I have tried both. But with none I am getting the output.